# Is continuous the same as uncountable in "continuous-time stochastic process"?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology

Is the word "continuous'' as used in "continuous-time stochastic process" or "continuous-time Markov chain'' synonymous with uncountable? Or is there a difference?

I'm wondering because I have seen definitions like the following for a stochastic process:

> A stochastic process is a set of random variables $\{X(t) \mid t \in
> > T\}$, indexed by a parameter $t$, where $t$ varies over an index set
>   $T$.

And state-space I have seen defined as "the set of values that the random variables can take."

Then later, when continuous-time Markov chains are introduced, some authors say that "chain" means that the state-space is countable (finite or countably infinite). But for the index set, they say that "continuous-time" means that it is continuous. So I'm wondering, is there a reason to designate the state space as countable or uncountable, but the index set as discrete or continuous? Would it be just as correct to say that "continuous-time" means that the index set is uncountable?  Or is is there a difference between uncountable and continuous?

Comment: continuous-time implies uncountability, the converse is not true. Consider the famous Cantor set example.

Comment: @Solitary This is obviously an old question, and I like your answer. OP raises a good point though -- can we create a rigorous definition of "continuous time", or is it just a non-precise intuitive phraseology meant to suggest similarities with the real line? For instance, discrete time necessarily refers to a countable index set (I think?). But as you correctly point at, uncountability shouldn't be a sufficient criterion for "continuous time". But what topological properties should be sufficient/necessary? Connectedness? path connectedness? one-dimensionality? homeomorphic to the real line?